# Updating another property based on a property, vice versa

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

My issue is I have three properties with mutually dependent in my WPF application. I have implemented InotifyPropertyChanged also for the class. I am not sure how to update second property based on other.

**Example:**

Properties : ActualValue, ChangedValue, Change

ActualValue is Fixed, and it is possible to update ChangedValue and Change.  That means if I update ChangedValue, the Change is calculated like (ActualValue-ChangedValue) and set.  And when Change updates, the ChangedValue will be calculated based on ActualValue and Change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the logic inside the setters of properties that others depend on.  Since it's a circular dependency, just make sure that inside the setters you change the private variable-- don't use the property setter, as that would create an infinite loop.  Like this:

```
private string _change, _changedValue;

public string ChangedValue {
    set { 
        _changedValue = value;
        _change = ActualValue - _changedValue;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ChangedValue");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Change");
    }
}


public string Change {
    set { 
        _change = value;
        _changedValue = ActualValue - _change;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Change");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ChangedValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to add RaisePropertyChanged events in both of the setters for "ChangeValue" and "Change" so that both are updated in any databinding to them.

Comment: You need to raise the ChangeValue AND Change in both of the setters as you have modified both values each time.

Comment: That makes sense! was helpful. I missed some basics. ;)